# Get tweet url having only tweet id

Tags: twitter

How can I get tweet URL having only the tweet id?

I found a solution but I want to know if there is a better one. First, I assume you have to do a query and search after the tweet id obtaining the user name, and after that build the URL as follows:

```
https://twitter.com/{username}/status/{tweetid}.
```

Is this correct? Is there an easier solution which doesn't imply doing the query first?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't *need* the username.

Here's one of my tweets

https://twitter.com/edent/status/552767187694661632

If you replace my Twitter name (edent) with any other random name....

https://twitter.com/barackobama/status/552767187694661632

When you click on that link, Twitter will look up the Status ID and automatically redirect you.

So, don't bother doing the query, just stick any random name in there and it will still work.

Comment: @Terance Eden do you have an idea if this is a safe solution?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "safe". It's been this way since 2012 - https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2012/05/interesting-twitter-hashbang-bug/ - I doubt they'll change it.

Comment: That surely does work. Thanks Eden for the answer!  @Jones, yes, there is a case originates when someone use this tweet id. If it is protected i.e your account is protected one. He'd not be able to see it.

Comment: Almost ending 2022 and it still works.

Answer (score 21):

It appears that https://twitter.com/statuses/{tweetid} suggested by anas-eqal no longer works consistently. Thus, I went hunting for an alternative. I concede that the accepted response, as of the time of this reply, works perfectly well. However, for my use case I needed a url that avoids a redirect and has a more consistent structure.

Here is what I came up with:

1. standard: https://twitter.com/i/web/status/{tweetid}
2. mobile:   https://mobile.twitter.com/i/web/status/{tweetid}

Both variants work well in all my tests to date.

Answer (score 7):

you can try this one:

https://twitter.com/statuses/{tweetid}

Answer (score 2):

u can use :
https://mobile.twitter.com/user/status/1247490140446097410
1247490140446097410 change it with your tweet id
user leave it him will change auto with username